# kotlin how to sort List<Map<String, Any>>?

Tags: java, kotlin

I want sort rawData according to the item `date`

```
val rawData: List<Map<String, Any>> = parseSampleData()

val sortData = rawData.sortedBy { it["date"] }
```

then error in `sortedBy` like this

```
Type parameter bound for R in 

inline fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> Iterable<T>.sortedBy
(
crossinline selector: (T) → R?
)
: List<T>
is not satisfied: inferred type Any is not a subtype of Comparable<Any>
```

also this not work

```
val sortedList = rawData.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.get("date") }))
```

with this error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Comparable<*>?
Found:
Any?
```

please help

Comment: The map value is declared as type `Any`, and `Any` is not `Comparable`. You can only sort values that can be compared, e.g. you can't compare apples and oranges. If you "know" that all values of a given map are of the same type, then you can cast to the *raw* `Comparable`, but you're throwing all type-safety away, and just blindly hoping the values are good at runtime. --- It is recommended that you re-design the code to not need a list like that, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to convert the date to either `LocalDate` or `ZonedDateTime`, which can then be compared.

```kotlin
import java.time.LocalDate

fun main() {
    val rawData: List<Map<String, Any>> = parseSampleData()
    val sortData = rawData.sortedBy { it["date"] as LocalDate }
    println(sortData)
}

fun parseSampleData() = listOf(
    mapOf("date" to LocalDate.parse("2020-01-03")),
    mapOf("date" to LocalDate.parse("2020-01-01")),
    mapOf("date" to LocalDate.parse("2020-01-02")),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing is that kotlin doesn't know how to sort objects of type `Any?`, which is what is returned by `it["date"]` and `it.get("date")`. If you know the type that is returned by `it["date"]`, then cast it to that type, provided it implements `Comparable` (I assume it is some kind of a date object which should be comparable). Otherwise you need to specity what your map contains in the value slot (again provided taht it implements `Comparable`).